# paperclip & aws gems - photo sharing app where are the urls stored by paperclip/aws?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, ios6, paperclip

Im referring to this app [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service) as a tutorial. After looking at it. Im curious to understand how the program (client or server)can accesse images. Since the program doesn't seem to be explicitely saving image urls in the server's database once they are uploaded to Amazon S3?

After implementing this app, I dont see a column for image_urls or path in the database. But the program magically loads images in the client!!

Something is going on under the hood, what is that something?

Here is the Photo model method:

```
 Paperclip.interpolates :prefix  do |attachment, style|
   "#{attachment.instance.takenby}/#{Date.today.to_s }/#   
  {attachment.instance.image_file_name}"
 end 

 has_attached_file :image,
                :path => ":prefix/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :styles => { :thumbnail => "57x57", :original => "300x300" },
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS


  validates :image,:presence => true
  validates :lat, :lng,:presence => true,:numericality => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there in the options for `has_attached_file`. You've told it how to construct the path for the image (which corresponds to its filename on s3) in the `:path` argument. So all paperclip needs to know to find the image again is:

1. The host name for your s3 bucket
2. The relevant information to re-construct the path - in this case, that looks like `:prefix`, `:basename`, `:style`, and `:extension`.

Most of that information is in your database. Presumably `:basename` comes from the original filename somehow, which ought to be saved in the `image_file_name` field of the model to which the image is attached. `:style` depends on which image size you're looking up at runtime. `:extension` can be determined from the `image_content_type` attribute.

`:prefix` is a little bit trickier. In fact, I worry that your interpolation rule will break your image lookup, because of the `Date.today` it uses to construct the prefix. Do you have any images more than one day old? If so, do they still work? I worry that when the image is uploaded, it will have a filename containing that day's date, and then when you go to find them in the future you'll reconstruct the url using the *new* current date, and wind up with a 403 error.

TL;DR paperclip constructs the image url when it uploads the images to s3, and reconstructs them later from the same parameters.

Comment: You hit the nail right on the head. The :prefix is exatcly what was causing the problem reconstructing the path! Images older than 1 day could not be retrieved. I have gone ahead and changed it. I was confused about how it worked, but now it all makes sense. Thanks a lot for clarifying.---------------------- +1 for this